# How to improve the a ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, time

I am using time use survey data to identify the timing of different activities. Below the plot that I made

[image]

However I find difficult to read and to identify different elements on this figure.For example due to the colours is difficult to identify activities (eg. colour are almost similar). What I want that activities to have different colours or different signs that makes them easier to identify

Is there a better way to represent this data? Many thanks.

The code that I am using

```
  plot<-ggplot(melted_Activities, aes(x = time,y = value,fill = variable)) + geom_col(stat = "identity", position="fill")


plot + labs(x="Time", y="Precentages", colour="Activties", fill="Activites")+theme(legend.position="right", axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 0))+ annotate("rect", fill = "black", alpha = 0.3, xmin = c(73), xmax = c(97), ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf) + scale_x_discrete(breaks = c( "04:00","05:00", "06:00", "07:00", "08:00", "09:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00","13:00", "14:00", "15:00", "16:00", "17:00", "18:00", "19:00", "20:00", "21:00","22:00", "23:00", "00:00", "01:00", "02:00", "03:00"), expand = c(0,0)) + scale_y_continuous(expand = c(-0,0), labels = scales::percent)
```

Below my data:

```
dput(head(melted_Activities,144))
structure(list(time = c("04:00", "04:10", "04:20", "04:30", "04:40", 
"04:50", "05:00", "05:10", "05:20", "05:30", "05:40", "05:50", 
"06:00", "06:10", "06:20", "06:30", "06:40", "06:50", "07:00", 
"07:10", "07:20", "07:30", "07:40", "07:50", "08:00", "08:10", 
"08:20", "08:30", "08:40", "08:50", "09:00", "09:10", "09:20", 
"09:30", "09:40", "09:50", "10:00", "10:10", "10:20", "10:30", 
"10:40", "10:50", "11:00", "11:10", "11:20", "11:30", "11:40", 
"11:50", "12:00", "12:10", "12:20", "12:30", "12:40", "12:50", 
"13:00", "13:10", "13:20", "13:30", "13:40", "13:50", "14:00", 
"14:10", "14:20", "14:30", "14:40", "14:50", "15:00", "15:10", 
"15:20", "15:30", "15:40", "15:50", "16:00", "16:10", "16:20", 
"16:30", "16:40", "16:50", "17:00", "17:10", "17:20", "17:30", 
"17:40", "17:50", "18:00", "18:10", "18:20", "18:30", "18:40", 
"18:50", "19:00", "19:10", "19:20", "19:30", "19:40", "19:50", 
"20:00", "20:10", "20:20", "20:30", "20:40", "20:50", "21:00", 
"21:10", "21:20", "21:30", "21:40", "21:50", "22:00", "22:10", 
"22:20", "22:30", "22:40", "22:50", "23:00", "23:10", "23:20", 
"23:30", "23:40", "23:50", "00:00", "00:10", "00:20", "00:30", 
"00:40", "00:50", "01:00", "01:10", "01:20", "01:30", "01:40", 
"01:50", "02:00", "02:10", "02:20", "02:30", "02:40", "02:50", 
"03:00", "03:10", "03:20", "03:30", "03:40", "03:50"), variable = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Personal care", 
"Sleep", "Eating", "Other personal care", "Employment", "Main job", 
"Second job", "Activites related to employment", "Study", "School or University", 
"Free time study", "House and family care", "Food management", 
"Household maintenance", "Making care for textiles", "Gardening and pet care", 
"Construction and repairs", "Shopping and services", "Household management", 
"Childcare of own household member", "Help to an adult household member", 
"Volunteer work and meeting", "Organisational work", "Informal help to others", 
"Participatory activties", "Social care", "Social life", "Entertainment and culture", 
"Resting", "Sport and outdoor activities", "Physical exercise", 
"Productive exercise", "Sportsrelated activities", "Hobbies, games and computing", 
"Arts and hobbies", "Computing", "PC Games", "Mass media", "Reading", 
"Tv and video", "Radio and music", "Travel and unspecified time use", 
"Travel by purpose", "Punctuating activity"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
144L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: What information are you trying to convey?

Comment: @corry many thanks how the timing of different activities changes during the day. The idea is to easily identify the timing of activities, to say that there is 75% chance that people at 4pm report spleep

Comment: Can you group these activities together into a handful of groups and use the same plot?

Comment: @that the issue these are already activity groups for example sleep is category that consists of 2 other groups.

Comment: This is really broad and seems to be partially a design question. How to display your data depends on lots of things: purpose, audience, where it will be printed, etc. Aside from all those context concerns, "better" is totally subjective. Try to narrow down what exactly you want to do, then ask for help with the discrete steps to get there

Comment: @camille Many thanks the purpose of this graph is to identify the timing of different activities however the colours are similar that makes the graph difficult to read. Is there a better way?

Comment: Maybe faceting by time of day? I am thinking in dividing the hours in periods of 6 hours. And maybe a line graph, the activities less present would be near the bottom.

Comment: @ Rui Barradas thank you but how to do that?

Comment: Yes, there are lots of better ways. Which one you want to do is completely dependent on those questions of context I put above. We don't know the specifics of those questions, and can't make that decision for you, so it's up to you to come up with what you want and why

Answer (score 2):

Following my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57597685/how-to-improve-the-a-ggplot#comment101653067_57597685) I was thinking of something like this.

```
time <- melted_Activities$time
time <- as.POSIXct(paste(Sys.Date(), time), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
melted_Activities$period <- cut(time, "6 hour")
melted_Activities$period <- format(melted_Activities$period, "%H:%M")
```

And then facet by `period` of 6 hours.

```
p <- ggplot(melted_Activities, aes(x = time,y = value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_col(position = "fill") +
  facet_wrap(~ period)
```

Or maybe a line graph.

```
p <- ggplot(melted_Activities, aes(x = time,y = value, colour = variable)) + 
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~ period)
```

Comment: Many thanks @Rui Barradas, one more question how can I get read of the date  - I need just hours

Comment: @user10974052 `melted_Activities$period <- format(melted_Activities$period, "%H:%M")`. I will edit the answer.